# RL circuit with thyristor not working as expected

Tags: resistors, ac, inductor, converter, thyristor

I'm trying to simulate the following circuit to test how it works:

[image]

The control circuit uses a PIC 18F4550.

The isolation circuit, and main circuit are these:

[image]

Unfortunately when I try to simulate this circuit on proteus,
i get the following signals as result

[image]

When I connect this circuit with a resistor and with ground connected
to the base of the circuit like this:
[image]

I get the expected result:

[image]

But if I add the inductor, the program doesn't show anything on the oscilloscope

[image]

What am I doing wrong?, What's the right way to connect the ground on this circuit?
Are there some additional considerations i should keep in mind?

Comment: Try reducing the value of the inductance. You also have grounded the common cathode for the SCRs in the first picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check your connections. The first picture you're showing doesn't have the best drawn conections, but you can infer that the commanding pulse is applied relative to the common point of the two SCRs.

Then, in your 1st schematic, you have grounded the common point, while in the 2nd you haven't. Both are not driven correctly, but it shows carelesness.

And the load you're using has a 400 mH inductor, which is a lot in terms of the time constant involved (40 seconds), so you may want to reduce it at least by a factor of 10.

With these in mind, here's the reworked schematic:

[image: test]

The driving is done relative to the common point of the two SCRs while the load has the same 100 Ω resistor but with a `.step`ped value for the inductance, whose current is plotted: 1 mH (black), 10 mH (blue), 100 mH (red), and 1 H (green).

The SCR used is a simple approximation with two BJTs, but it works pretty decent and it's at the basis of many commercial models for SCRs (Littlefuse, for example). The diodes are randomly chosen.